# Firebase multilingual Password Reset Email

Tags: firebase, multilingual, firebasesimplelogin

Hello all !

There is a service provided with Firebase (and all its awesomeness) that gives the possibility for an authenticated user to reset his password. But this service is taking only one text into account - the one defined on the dashboard.

Is it possible to get this in many languages ? I'm going to need this functionnality !

@Firebase Friends, since I think you will see this question - do you plan to add this in the future ? Or else give the possibility to pass a text as an argument to the function ?

Thanks ahead !

Comment: @rob-diMarco may help you (he is backend engineer in Firebase) http://stackoverflow.com/users/879295/rob-dimarco

Comment: Please reach out to support@firebase com for this feature request. Stackoverflow is not the right forum for it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about adding a feature to Firebase.

Comment: Sure, for the feature request I will try and reach them... But Stackoverflow is definitely the place for an eventual workaround, right ? :)

Comment: Sure. But I can't think of anything besides sending a single multi-lingual email (the typical "scroll down for english"). I'm also quite sure you won't find that acceptable (I wouldn't).

Comment: No, it's not acceptable. Actually the only way I could think of would be coding again the functionnality, upon request sending the email to a dedicated adress watched by a program, that would take the new temporary password, integrate it into a text of the wanted language, and send it to the right person. But it's a lot of work for something that should be straightforward (I contacted Firebase and they have no plan to add this feature in the near future...)

Comment: Hey, this post is quite old. Did they do something about it? I would need the same feature.

Comment: @cherry-wave I gave up on this long time ago, and didn't check for at least a year if they did something... I guess from your answer they didn't. Good luck.

Comment: I need this too! Is the feature already available?

Comment: I have added an answer to this post describing how you can have multilingual password reset mails, but only for pre-defined templates

Comment: What if the user uses the app on multiple devices and each device has a different language. Then this will work `auth.useAppLanguage();` or `auth.setLanguageCode("fr");`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using the standard Firebase email service you can currently have multilingual emails *only* if you use the standard template provided by Firebase. If you have a customised template you can reset it in the console. To send locale specific mails you should manually call the function to use the device language or set it with a string. These scenarios are provided as examples below:

[Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email):

```
firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage(); // set with function
firebase.auth().languageCode = 'fr'; // set with string
```

[Android SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email):

```
auth.useAppLanguage(); // set with function
auth.setLanguageCode("fr"); // set with string
```

[Swift SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email):

```
Auth.auth().useAppLanguage(); // set with function
Auth.auth().languageCode = "fr"; // set with string
```

The [Google Groups mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/translate%7Csort:date/firebase-talk/WOa_MpxFETU/NVdY2IbdGAAJ) has a nice discussion of these issues.

Another solution is to use custom email action handlers. The setup is more difficult but it is well documented in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler).

Comment: Hey, thanks but you do realize I asked this 4 years ago ? :D Everything has changed since ! Thanks again anyway, I will have a look at the new capabilities of FB

Comment: Sure. I just stumbled upon it because I wanted to do the same, and now I figured out how. So for anyone else coming along it might be nice for them not to search so much for it :-)

Comment: Well, since no one had answered this question, there you get some points I guess

Comment: @eikooc or JeremyBelolo do you know if the hosted reset password google page identifies the browser language?

Comment: @eikooc I suppose there is no way to remove the project name in the standard email, which appears like this: project-2345234523? Right?